# Why won't the image align vertical / center in these containers?

Tags: html, css

I have seen similar questions and this began by using the answer provided:

```css
.wraptocenter {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.wraptocenter * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="https://img.xcitefun.net/users/2015/01/382650,xcitefun-philippines-tour-1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
```

It doesn't work as I want. I want my `wraptocenter` div  containers to float one after he other and go down to the next row. If I remove `float` then they center but all of then squish on one row. When I add `float` the image is no longer centered vertically.

In the final HTMl I will want to use various images of different dimensions, all of which should be central.

I don't want to use any special elements (like flex grids). Just basic html / css.
[image]

Comment: why don't you want to use flex?  absolute positioning and float should be used as little as possible.

Comment: @DCR See my comment on the answer provided.

Answer (score 1):

`Flex` is the ideal solution for this. But as that is undesired. A solution would be to remove the **static** `width` and `height` you have set on `.wraptocenter` and use `padding` instead.

```css
.wraptocenter {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em 1em;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><img src="http://www.brunildo.org/thumb/tmiri2_o.jpg" /></div>
```

`Flex` solution with the **static** parent height and width. [A Fiddle for Andrew](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/3srygqL0/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but, when I introduce other images, like a portrait image in the next container, the size for that one is taller. I want all containers to be grid like.

For now, I have opted for not using flex because I am still using a CHtmlView control which won't support it. Eventually I will use WebView2 where a flex could be used.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle No problem. Can you post an example or link a fiddle to show me what you mean when you have the portrait image and I can give you a solution for that one? Would a `flex` solution be helpful in addition to my current solution for when you use WebView2? Personal opinion - anything that doesn't support `flex` is outmoded. @gmail

Comment: I have updated the question by just adding another graphic from a public website. It conveys the idea. I know CHtmlView is now outdated, but WebView2 is new and it has some crippling limitations which, until resolved, mean it is not suitable to use in my live application.

Comment: And yes, a flex solution would be helpful in addition. Eventually I will use WebView2 and I would be able to migrate over to that methodology. I have never used it.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Do you want the image to render the same size as the other images? Like [this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwyPj.png) or something like [this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gafVQ.png)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Here is the `flex` solution with the **static** parent height and width. [A Fiddle for Andrew](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/3srygqL0/1/). If you're doing a lot of front-end work I would recommend mastering `flex`.

Comment: Those are all useful. Ideally I wanted to end up with ageneric solution because ultimately I am using this to create a worksheet and it will vary from week to week what images are in it. So no matter their dimensions I wanted them to fit into a fixed thumbnail. That was why I used static sizes. Ultimately this HTML output is to be printed and fit on a A4 worksheet.

Comment: This works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869078/2287576

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245276/discussion-between-kameron-and-andrew-truckle).

Answer (score 0):

Put these images as background-image for those divs. Btw you can make it responsive like that easily